# Translating WINBUGS model to JAGS model: possible directed cycle

Tags: bayesian, jags, winbugs

I am practicing Bayesian and trying to translate WINBUGS models into JAGS in R. I have looked the JAGS manual and still haven't been able to work out this one, which gives error - Possible directed cycle involving some or all of the following nodes.

The example is taken from the paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jrsm.1112

Anyone can give me some directions, please?

````
model{
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    # Calculate probabilities:
    P[i, 1, 1] <- p[i, 1]
    P[i, 1, 2] <- P[i, 1, 1] + (1-p[i,1])*p[i,2]
    P[i, 1, 3] <- P[i, 1, 2] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*p[i,3]
    P[i, 1, 4] <- P[i, 1, 3] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 1, 5] <- P[i, 1, 4] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 1, 6] <- P[i, 1, 5] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 1, 7] <- P[i, 1, 6] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 2, 2] <- p[i, 2]
    P[i, 2, 3] <- P[i, 2, 2] + (1-p[i,2])*p[i,3]
    P[i, 2, 4] <- P[i, 2, 3] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 2, 5] <- P[i, 2, 4] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 2, 6] <- P[i, 2, 5] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 2, 7] <- P[i, 2, 6] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 3, 3] <- p[i, 3]
    P[i, 3, 4] <- P[i, 3, 3] + (1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 3, 5] <- P[i, 3, 4] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 3, 6] <- P[i, 3, 5] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 3, 7] <- P[i, 3, 6] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 4, 4] <- p[i, 4]
    P[i, 4, 5] <- P[i, 4, 4] + (1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 4, 6] <- P[i, 4, 5] + (1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 4, 7] <- P[i, 4, 6] + (1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 5, 5] <- p[i, 5]
    P[i, 5, 6] <- P[i, 5, 5] + (1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 5, 7] <- P[i, 5, 6] + (1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 6, 6] <- p[i, 6]
    P[i, 6, 7] <- P[i, 6, 6] + (1-p[i,6])* p[i,7]
    P[i, 7, 7] <- p[i, 7]

    logit(p[i,1])<-mu[1] + delta[study[i],1]
    for(k in 2:7)
    {
      p[i,k]<-max((exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])*(1+exp(mu[k-1]+delta[study[i],(k-1)]))-exp(mu[k-1]+delta[study[i],(k-1)])*(1+exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])))/(1+exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])))  
    }
    
    #Model outcomes; start and end are the start and end of the intervals the deaths occur in (denoted by j and k in the paper) 
    probs[i]<-P[study[i], start[i], end[i]]
    D[i]~dbin(probs[i], N[i])
    
  }
  
  # Generate random effects:
  for(i in 1:studies)
  {
    delta[i, 1:7]~ dmnorm(zero[] , Omega[,]) 
  }
  
  #Convert odds to probabilities. theta[1:7] are the parameters of primary interest.
  for(i in 1:7)
  {
    theta[i]<-exp(mu[i])/(1+exp(mu[i]))
  }
  
  # Priors
  mu[1]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(, mu[2])
  mu[2]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[1], mu[3])
  mu[3]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[2], mu[4])
  mu[4]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[3], mu[5])
  mu[5]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[4], mu[6])
  mu[6]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[5], mu[7])
  mu[7]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[6], )
  Omega[1 : 7 , 1 : 7]  ~ dwish(R[ , ], 7)  
  Sigma[1 : 7 , 1 : 7] <- inverse(Omega[ , ])
}


DATA <- list(studies=50, 
             D=c(85, 10, 108, 11, 27, 22, 87, 52, 220, 103, 61, 45, 32, 89, 
                     70, 291, 245, 155, 62, 14, 17, 83, 3, 20, 32, 0, 18, 0, 28, 0, 
                     40, 2, 31, 0, 5, 3, 2, 31, 4, 268, 80, 1, 1, 10, 3, 109, 41, 
                     864, 26, 74, 2, 5, 13, 113, 41, 13, 38, 38, 187, 5, 6, 8, 1, 
                     15, 6, 24, 33, 1, 118, 1288, 8, 7, 11, 51, 37, 39, 13, 65, 0, 
                     28, 31, 15, 6, 14, 20, 26, 22, 2, 20, 8, 17, 33, 15, 209, 89, 
                     44, 23, 11, 11, 261, 873, 8, 9, 10, 13, 7, 9, 22, 12, 21, 39, 
                     8, 71, 22, 107), 
             N=c(525, 171, 161, 208, 197, 170, 1039, 584, 532, 312, 209, 148, 
                103, 278, 1425, 1355, 1064, 819, 149, 106, 92, 510, 101, 98, 
                78, 197, 197, 106, 106, 155, 155, 103, 101, 108, 108, 103, 103, 
                101, 554, 550, 241, 140, 139, 138, 128, 259, 150, 1840, 376, 
                350, 137, 135, 314, 301, 443, 402, 229, 1404, 1366, 180, 175, 
                113, 105, 145, 108, 102, 78, 993, 992, 5787, 220, 212, 205, 194, 
                143, 134, 526, 513, 100, 100, 72, 41, 169, 163, 149, 129, 103, 
                235, 233, 213, 205, 188, 155, 1560, 1351, 120, 108, 85, 74, 4929, 
                4668, 109, 101, 92, 82, 69, 103, 94, 213, 201, 180, 395, 387, 
                315, 293), 
             start=c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 
                     4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                     1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                     2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 
                     2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
                     4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
             end=c(3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 
                   5, 4, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 
                   1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 
                   3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 
                   3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
                   4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 7), 
             n=115, study=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 
                            9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
                            17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 
                            26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 
                            34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 
                            40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 
                            45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50), 
             zero = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) , 
             R = cbind(c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0 ), c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2,0,0),
                       c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,2,0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,2)))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

WinBUGS was rather lax about allowing directed cycles in the model graph, but JAGS is much stricter. Your directed cycle is here:

```
mu[1]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(, mu[2])
mu[2]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[1], mu[3])
mu[3]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[2], mu[4])
mu[4]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[3], mu[5])
mu[5]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[4], mu[6])
mu[6]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[5], mu[7])
mu[7]~dnorm(0,0.001) I(mu[6], )
```

But you can achieve the same thing this way:

```
for(i in 1:7){
  umu[i] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
}
mu <- sort(umu)
```

The model then compiles (reproducible R code below) but I get an error that node D[5] is inconsistent with parents, which means that you need to set some sensible initial values.

R code is as follows - the model compiles, so the directed cycle is fixed:

```
mod <- "model{
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    # Calculate probabilities:
    P[i, 1, 1] <- p[i, 1]
    P[i, 1, 2] <- P[i, 1, 1] + (1-p[i,1])*p[i,2]
    P[i, 1, 3] <- P[i, 1, 2] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*p[i,3]
    P[i, 1, 4] <- P[i, 1, 3] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 1, 5] <- P[i, 1, 4] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 1, 6] <- P[i, 1, 5] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 1, 7] <- P[i, 1, 6] + (1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 2, 2] <- p[i, 2]
    P[i, 2, 3] <- P[i, 2, 2] + (1-p[i,2])*p[i,3]
    P[i, 2, 4] <- P[i, 2, 3] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 2, 5] <- P[i, 2, 4] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 2, 6] <- P[i, 2, 5] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 2, 7] <- P[i, 2, 6] + (1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 3, 3] <- p[i, 3]
    P[i, 3, 4] <- P[i, 3, 3] + (1-p[i,3])*p[i,4]
    P[i, 3, 5] <- P[i, 3, 4] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 3, 6] <- P[i, 3, 5] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 3, 7] <- P[i, 3, 6] + (1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 4, 4] <- p[i, 4]
    P[i, 4, 5] <- P[i, 4, 4] + (1-p[i,4])*p[i,5]
    P[i, 4, 6] <- P[i, 4, 5] + (1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 4, 7] <- P[i, 4, 6] + (1-p[i,4])*(1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 5, 5] <- p[i, 5]
    P[i, 5, 6] <- P[i, 5, 5] + (1-p[i,5])*p[i,6]
    P[i, 5, 7] <- P[i, 5, 6] + (1-p[i,5])*(1-p[i,6])*p[i,7]
    P[i, 6, 6] <- p[i, 6]
    P[i, 6, 7] <- P[i, 6, 6] + (1-p[i,6])* p[i,7]
    P[i, 7, 7] <- p[i, 7]

    logit(p[i,1])<-mu[1] + delta[study[i],1]
    for(k in 2:7)
    {
      p[i,k]<-max((exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])*(1+exp(mu[k-1]+delta[study[i],(k-1)]))-exp(mu[k-1]+delta[study[i],(k-1)])*(1+exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])))/(1+exp(mu[k]+delta[study[i],k])))  
    }

    #Model outcomes; start and end are the start and end of the intervals the deaths occur in (denoted by j and k in the paper) 
    probs[i]<-P[study[i], start[i], end[i]]
    D[i]~dbin(probs[i], N[i])

  }

  # Generate random effects:
  for(i in 1:studies)
  {
    delta[i, 1:7]~ dmnorm(zero[] , Omega[,]) 
  }

  #Convert odds to probabilities. theta[1:7] are the parameters of primary interest.
  for(i in 1:7)
  {
    theta[i]<-exp(mu[i])/(1+exp(mu[i]))
  }

  # Priors
  for(i in 1:7){
    umu[i] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
  }
  mu <- sort(umu)

  Omega[1 : 7 , 1 : 7]  ~ dwish(R[ , ], 7)  
  Sigma[1 : 7 , 1 : 7] <- inverse(Omega[ , ])
}"


DATA <- list(studies=50, 
  D=c(85, 10, 108, 11, 27, 22, 87, 52, 220, 103, 61, 45, 32, 89, 
    70, 291, 245, 155, 62, 14, 17, 83, 3, 20, 32, 0, 18, 0, 28, 0, 
    40, 2, 31, 0, 5, 3, 2, 31, 4, 268, 80, 1, 1, 10, 3, 109, 41, 
    864, 26, 74, 2, 5, 13, 113, 41, 13, 38, 38, 187, 5, 6, 8, 1, 
    15, 6, 24, 33, 1, 118, 1288, 8, 7, 11, 51, 37, 39, 13, 65, 0, 
    28, 31, 15, 6, 14, 20, 26, 22, 2, 20, 8, 17, 33, 15, 209, 89, 
    44, 23, 11, 11, 261, 873, 8, 9, 10, 13, 7, 9, 22, 12, 21, 39, 
    8, 71, 22, 107), 
  N=c(525, 171, 161, 208, 197, 170, 1039, 584, 532, 312, 209, 148, 
    103, 278, 1425, 1355, 1064, 819, 149, 106, 92, 510, 101, 98, 
    78, 197, 197, 106, 106, 155, 155, 103, 101, 108, 108, 103, 103, 
    101, 554, 550, 241, 140, 139, 138, 128, 259, 150, 1840, 376, 
    350, 137, 135, 314, 301, 443, 402, 229, 1404, 1366, 180, 175, 
    113, 105, 145, 108, 102, 78, 993, 992, 5787, 220, 212, 205, 194, 
    143, 134, 526, 513, 100, 100, 72, 41, 169, 163, 149, 129, 103, 
    235, 233, 213, 205, 188, 155, 1560, 1351, 120, 108, 85, 74, 4929, 
    4668, 109, 101, 92, 82, 69, 103, 94, 213, 201, 180, 395, 387, 
    315, 293), 
  start=c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 
    2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
  end=c(3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 
    5, 4, 1, 4, 7, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 
    1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 
    3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 7), 
  n=115, study=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 
    9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 
    26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 
    34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 
    40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 
    45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50), 
  zero = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) , 
  R = cbind(c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0 ), c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0,0,0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2,0,0),
    c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,2,0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,2)))

runjags::run.jags(mod, "mu", DATA)
```